# Threejs: PropertyBinding: Cannot parse trackName: .bones[].position

Tags: javascript, parsing, animation, three.js

Version: THREE.WebGLRenderer 91dev

I'm trying to get a simple animation for a chest opening to work in three.js, but I keep getting the following error when attempting to create an action.

> PropertyBinding: Cannot parse trackName: .bones[].position

The full version of the animation JSON object is here on pastebin: [Full JSON String](https://pastebin.com/raw/XH4PBvLQ). A short summary is below:

```
{
    "name": null,
    "fps": 30,
    "length": 0.5333333333333333,
    "hierarchy": [{
                "parent": -1,
                "keys": [{
                            "time": 0,
                            "rot": [
                                0,
                                0,
                                0,
                                1
                            ],
                            "scl": [
                                1,
                                1,
                                1
                            ],
                            "pos": [
                                0,
                                0,
                                0
                            ]
                        },
```

I create an Animation clip with the following commands.

```
    var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.parseAnimation(animation, armSkeleton.bones);
    geometry.animations.push(clip);
```

The value of clip is as follows:

```
duration: 0.6
name: "default"
tracks: […]
0: Object {
    name: ".bones[].position",
    times: […],
    values: […],
    …
}
1: Object {
    name: ".bones[].quaternion",
    times: […],
    values: […],
    …
}
2: Object {
    name: ".bones[].scale",
    times: […],
    values: […],
    …
}
3: Object {
    name: ".bones[].position",
    times: […],
    values: […],
    …
}
4: Object {
    name: ".bones[].quaternion",
    times: […],
    values: […],
    …
}
5: Object {
    name: ".bones[].scale",
    times: […],
    values: […],
    …
}
length: 6
__proto__: Array[]
uuid: "3E37E10B-74D0-4421-92AF-7A366CF3804F"
```

The problem is when I try and use the clip with:

```
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);
mixer.clipAction(mesh.geometry.animations[0]).play();
```

I get the error that threejs cannot parse the trackname ".bones.position" even though that's the name that the parseAnimation function returns? I'm super confused if anyone can point out something stupid I'm doing I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the problem some more I found the reason for the error was because AnimationClip expects the bones to be named. So managed to get this error to go away by simply giving each bone a unique name before passing it into THREE.AnimationClip.parseAnimation.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve this! You may want to file a bug if you're creating the animation with the three.js Blender exporter, perhaps it could have detected this or given a warning..

Comment: Parsing the model and animation were all done inside the browser, so it's not a fault with the Blender exporter.